How do I determine which line has too many arguments within the script itself?
When I run the script I get the following errors:
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
./A_High_Stakes_investigations.sh: line 31: check_files: command not found
Exiting script because directories or files already exist.

Why am I seeing these errors? Any suggestions on how to remedy this?
#Define the directories and files for verification

DIRS_TO_CHECK=("/Lucky_Duck_Investigations" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Dealer_Analysis" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Player_Analysis" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Player_Dealer_Correlation")

FILES_TO_CHECK=("/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Dealer_Analysis/Notes_Dealer_Analysis.txt" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Player_Analysis/Notes_Player_Analysis.txt" "/Lucky_Duck_Investigations/Roulette_Loss_Investigation/Player_Dealer_Correlation/Notes_Player_Dealer_Correlation.txt")

#Checking for existing directories
check_dirs() {
    for dir in "${DIRS_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        if [ -d "$dir ]; then
            echo "Error: Directory '$dir' exists."
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

#Checking for existing files
check_files() { 
    for file in "${FILES_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        if [ -f "$file ]; then
            echo "Error: File '$file' exists." 
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

#Executing main script
if check_dirs && check_files; then
    echo "Now creating the necessary directories and file for the evidence collection process:"

    #Listing the structure
    for dir in "${DIRS_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        echo "Directory: $dir"
    done

    for file in "${FILES_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        echo "File: $file"
    done

    #Creating the directories
    for dir in "${DIRS_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        mkdir -p "$dir"
    done

    for file in "{FILES_TO_CHECK[@]}"; do
        touch "$file"
    done

    echo "All directories and files have been created successfully."
else
    echo "Exiting script because directories or files already exist."
   exit 1
fi


[ -d "$dir ] and [ -f "$file ]. Fix the quoting.

Really, that stinking easy to spot.

Why does it create a text file '{FILES_TO_CHECK[@]}' and not for '{DIRECTORIES_TO_CHECK[@]}?  Also, it is not creating the empty text files either.

Use shellcheck.net to find simple/common mistakes in your script.
